# What was the highest bounty ever posted?

Tags: discussion, bounties

What is the amount of the highest single bounty ever posted?

Is there a limit to how much rep you can spend on a single bounty?

Comment: Non closed version: http://religion.blogs.cnn.com/2010/06/02/a-mandala-in-minutes/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the beginning, the biggest amount of reputation one can give in a single bounty is 500, as mentioned [in the faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).

However, in the beginning the system added 50 reputation on top of any bounty that was started making it an actual +550 award when the user gave 500.

This was changed in [June 2010](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/):

> The system no longer tosses in +50 bonus reputation to a bounty. We feel this newer, much more open bounty system no longer needs that incentive.

Comment: Any Link to reference?

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/396367/what-are-the-highest-bounties