# Is there any way to determine the highest bounties ever awarded?

Tags: discussion, bounties

A similar question was asked 3 years ago [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45809/what-was-the-highest-bounty-ever-posted), I'm sure the correct answer has changed since then:

What was the highest bounty ever awarded to an answer?  And, how do I find the corresponding question?

Comment: "What was the highest bounty ever awarded to a question?" - zero. You can't award bounties to questions. :D

Comment: A single bounty can only be up to 500, so I'm assuming you want the highest cumulative amount of bounties on a single answer?

Comment: Yes.  Didn't see how to do it in Data Explorer, maybe I missed the appropriate field.

Comment: I was feeling very inquisitive that day...

Answer (score 5):

Here's my version of the query:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/162721/answers-with-the-most-bounty-points

There are a total of 11 answers with more than 1000 rep from bounties.

The most of which is this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864000
Which gained +1500 from 5 bounties.

Answer (score 4):

Using [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/162717):

```sql
SELECT SUM(BountyAmount), PostId FROM Votes
WHERE VoteTypeId=9 AND BountyAmount>0
GROUP BY PostId
ORDER BY SUM(BountyAmount) DESC
```

It looks like the highest cumulative amount is only +1500 on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863870/how-should-a-model-be-structured-in-mvc/5864000#5864000).