# Strange duplicate stigma for the "highest bounty ever posted"

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

[What was the highest bounty ever posted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45809) is marked as a duplicate of [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065).

Although they both deal with bounties and the duplicate reference mentions the highest theoretical value for a bounty, aforementioned question asks about the highest values of instances of bounties.

How can the duplication be justified in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct closure.

The question is essentially "what is the maximum bounty?" and it's clearly answered in the faq. (500)

Looks like that in the past it was 550, I'll try to edit the faq when fidning the source.

Comment: Though, would a question like "What is the **answer** with the highest **total** bounty reward" be valid?

Comment: @devRicher sure, pretty sure it was asked already. And... [here it is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269743/which-answer-has-earned-highest-bounty-in-se-network).